# matlab: read subsection of an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a sequence of large images I would like to load into matlab and then apply some processing too. Due to the images size, reading them in takes a long time, and fills the computer memory very fast.

However, I am only interested in the middle section of the images, a region of about 100 by 100 pixels or so.

Is there a way to only read in that section of the image, therefore saving time, and memory?

Currently I am using:

```
ROIx = 450:550;
ROIy = 650:750;
image = double( imread( filename ) );
image = image(ROIx, ROIy);
```

However, imread() loads the whole image, and this takes a long time. Is there a way only to read the part I am interested in?

(One procedure would be to go through and crop each image into a smaller one and resave it. But I would prefer not to crop the images).

Thanks,
labjunky

Comment: You didn't specify neither the file format, bit depth nor the color model (grayscale, RGB, some other?). That data would be useful in finding an alternative solution.

Comment: They are greyscale, 1024 by 1392 pixels, 16 bit tiff images.

Comment: I don't think Matlab has any simple way of doing this. Depending on the format, you might be able to write your own image loader using [memory mapping](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/memmapfile.html) for random access to the file. You'd need a pretty strong understanding of the format to write that though.

Comment: it seems unlikely that Matlab would not be able to load a single 1024 x 1392 16 bit image. How many are you loading at once? Do you run out of memory when loading a single image?

Comment: It seems that a general TIFF loader will be quite complicated to code, but if you're using TIFFs produced by only one program with identical image parametres (size, bit depth, packing etc.), the task will be a lot easier. TIFF specification seems to have a StripOffsets field, and then from StripOffsets you could get each row's offset, I presume. However, the interpretation of data is not trivial, as TIFF supports several different compression methods. If you're using Linux, you could try `cmp -l -n 142 image1.tiff image2.tiff` to see in which header bytes there's difference between files.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your comment. I need to load around 100 images. My processing application takes a weighted linear combination of those images, in such a way as to minimise fringes in a separate "master" image.

Comment: Hello everyone, thank you for your replies! I have found the reason that matlab is running out of memory when I try to load many images. Infact loading the images doesn't take much memory at all, but after I load then I place them in a Cell Array, using num2cell(). This is the killer! It uses all my memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab 2012a indicates that you can read parts of images from JPEG2000 and TIFF images.  Look at the documentation for imread, inspect the option 'PixelRegion' for reading TIFFs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like [fopen](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fopen.html) to open the file and read the contents in parts manually. You will need to take care of lot of encoding/decoding of course. Or the other way round a little more would be to increase your system's [swap space.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/brh72ex-49.html) If you are getting out of memory errors.